# Python not referencing to same list

Tags: python

In code below:

```
a=[0,1]
b=a
for i in range(2):
    for j in b:
        a=a+[j]
```

why does a print as:

```
[0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

and b as:

```
[0,1]
```

However when executed on idle both lists change:

```
>>> c=[9,0]
>>> d=c
>>> d+=[7]
>>> c
[9, 0, 7]
```

Since a is being appended, why doesn't b change as is the property of python list assignment?

Comment: Why do you expect `b` to change? You do *not* append, you each time construct a *new* list, and assign it to `a`.

Comment: change `a=a+[j]` to `a.append(j)` to avoid reassignment of `a`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Since `a` is <s>being appended</s> why doesn't `b` change as is the property of python list assignment?

`a` is **not** appended. When you write:

```
a = a+[j]
```

you each time construct a list `[j]` and then construct a *new* list `a+[j]` that contains all the elements of `a` and then `j`.

Now you let `a` refer to the new list, but `b` *still* refers to the old list. Since the old list is not updated (the state is not altered, for instance through `append`), the list remains the same (which is good since iterating over a list you alter can have unwanted side effects).

If you would use `a.append(j)` or `a += [j]` instead of `a = a + [j]`, then the list will be *updated* (in the latter case, you implicitly call `a.extends([j])`). Since both `a` and `b` refer to that list, `b` will thus also be updated. But mind that since we iterate over `b` at the same time, we could end up in an infinite loop. So you better do not do that anyway.

Comment: Better than my answer =) deleted mine, could you add a mention to `a.append(j)` being the right way to do it?

Comment: @slezica:I would not call it the right way, since `append` changes the state of the object while iterating over it. One should definitely not advice this.

Comment: @William Right, like how subtraction isn't correct. Except, wait, sometimes it's the tool you have to use. There are cases -- for example, one frustratingly designed API I used recently -- where you need to know how to append in place.

Comment: Sorry for being late but a follow up. Why are both the lists changing now: `>>>c=[9,0]
>>> d=c
>>> d+=[7]
>>> c` # giving output as [9,0,7]

Comment: @akp: because `+=` does *not* create a new list, it extends the list, so both lists are modified. `a += b` is *not* always the same as `a = a+b` in Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining.

Answer (score 5):

`a` is not appended. Appending is done with the `append` command like so:

```
a.append(1)
```

Every time you add (`a + [j]`) you construct a new object.